# How to load javascript programmatically in Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app that will run as a kiosk. The problem I've ran into is that Chrome apps like to be "one" page so loading different content is not as simple as just linking to another page. What I've done is loaded my pages with jQuery `.load()`. The probem I'm running into now is that each of these pages has some HTML5 video that uses the JPlayer plugin. On these pages I had some inline js that would make the video player work. However, inline JS is a no-no in a Chrome app (UGH!). Is there a way I can dynamically load javascript into my app when I click something? Rgiht now I have something like this..

```
$(".video_list a").click(function(){
    $(".screen").load("video.html", function(){
        $.getScript("video.js");
    });
});
```

`video.js` would contain the JPlayer settings to create the video player. When I run this as just a regular webpage in the browser it works, but when its a Chrome App its doesn't work and I get no errors, just an empty div where the video should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this, because it's inline code again - `getScript` loads the script as text, then `eval`s it.

To work around it, you can insert the script as a `<script src="...">` tag:

```
function loadScript(name) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(name);
  s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  };
  (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!